# How to make my script use a CSV file that was given in the terminal as a parameter

Tags: ruby, csv

I tried to google this, but cant really find "good words" to get to my solution. So maybe someone here can help me out.

I have a script (lets call it **script.rb**) that uses File.read to read a csv file called **somefile.csv** and i have another csv file called **somefileV2.csv**.

**Script.rb**

```
csv_text = File.read('/home/XXX/XXX/XXX/somefile.csv')
```

Right now it uses **somefile.csv** as default, but I would like to know, if it is posseble to make my script use a CSV file that was given in the terminal as a parameter like:

**Terminal**

```
home$ script.rb somefileV2
```

so instead of it reading the file that is in the script, it reads the other csv file (**somefileV2.csv**) that is in the directory. It is kinda annoying to change the file manually everytime in the script itself.

Comment: [Command Line Arguments with ARGV](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/ruby-command-line-argv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the parameters (arguments) using the `ARGV` array.

So your program could be like:

```
default = "/home/XXX/XXX/XXX/somefile.csv"
csv_text = File.read(ARGV[0] || default)
```

which gives you the possibility to supply a filename or, if not supplied, use the default value.

`ARGV[0]` refers to the first, `ARGV[1]` to the second argument and so on.

`ruby myscript.rb foo bar baz` would result in `ARGV` being 
´["foo", "bar", "baz"]´. Note that the elements will always be strings. So if you want anything else (Numbers, Date, ...) you need to process it accordingly in your program.